# decrease each row by percent of previous row, by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data that looks like this:

| season | player | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | K. Bryant | 700 |
| 2 | K. Bryant | 700 |
| 3 | K. Bryant | 700 |
| 4 | K. Bryant | 700 |
| 1 | P. Pierce | 750 |
| 2 | P. Pierce | 750 |
| 3 | P. Pierce | 750 |

I want to decrease the minutes for each season by 10% of the minutes in the previous season. Each player does not have the same number of rows. I want something like the following:

| season | player | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | K. Bryant | 700 |
| 2 | K. Bryant | 630 |
| 3 | K. Bryant | 567 |
| 4 | K. Bryant | 510 |
| 1 | P. Pierce | 750 |
| 2 | P. Pierce | 675 |
| 3 | P. Pierce | 608 |

any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: Let us see what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a series of keep percentages with [groupby cumprod](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumprod.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-cumprod)

```
pct = .1
# Create a column with keep percentage as 1 - .1
df['keep_pct'] = (1 - pct)
# Groupby for player and keep_pct
g = df.groupby('player')['keep_pct']

# Shift to prevent affecting the first row of each group
# fill_value with 1 so first row is 100%
df['keep_pct'] = g.shift(fill_value=1)

# Cumprod to compound the keep percentage
df['keep_pct'] = g.cumprod()

# Multiply minutes and keep_pct columns
df['minutes'] = df['minutes'].mul(df['keep_pct']).round(0).astype(int)

# Cleanup Columns
df = df.drop(columns='keep_pct')
```

`df`:

```
   season     player  minutes
0       1  K. Bryant      700
1       2  K. Bryant      630
2       3  K. Bryant      567
3       4  K. Bryant      510
4       1  P. Pierce      750
5       2  P. Pierce      675
6       3  P. Pierce      608
```

`df['keep_pct']`:

```
0    1.000
1    0.900
2    0.810
3    0.729
4    1.000
5    0.900
6    0.810
Name: keep_pct, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward solution, exploiting how the dataframe is sorted:

```py
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.player[i] == df.player[i-1]:
        df.loc[i, 'minutes'] = 0.9 * df.loc[i-1, 'minutes']

df
```

```
    season  player  minutes
0   1   K. Bryant   700.0
1   2   K. Bryant   630.0
2   3   K. Bryant   567.0
3   4   K. Bryant   510.3
4   1   P. Pierce   750.0
5   2   P. Pierce   675.0
6   3   P. Pierce   607.5
```